# How to Delete all entries under HKCR windows 10 using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, registry

How can I delete all the entries under HKCR registry key?

I tried the following but not working

```
reg delete HKCR /f
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to clear the HKCR key for legitimate purposes? That would wipe out so much registration info as to make the system practically unusable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau For learning purposes.

Comment: @KJ Do you any procedure in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and break your system:

It is my understanding that you need to use `ROOTKEY\SubKey`, so without a SubKey, I doubt it would work, although I'm not foolish enough to try it.

I'd expect that you'd need to enumerate all of the top level SubKeys in a `For /F` loop, then perform a `Delete` on each result:

Open a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window, type the following, then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```sh
For /F Delims^= %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKCR') Do %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "%G" /F 1>NUL 2>&1
```

---

To do this as a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), it would look like this:

```sh
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKCR'
) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "%%G" /F 1>NUL 2>&1
```

---

BTW, [as mentioned by KJ, in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879204/how-to-delete-all-entries-under-hkcr-windows-10-using-batch-file/67879520?noredirect=1#comment119981802_67879204) under the question proper, the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key is not really a root key like the others, it is really a combination of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`, and the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes` ROOTKEY\SubKey pair. Perhaps you should therefore see what happens if you try to delete both of those instead, as the `Delete` command works for those.

Just a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```sh
@For %%G In (LM CU) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "HK%%G\SOFTWARE\Classes" /F 1>NUL 2>&1
```

With the `2>&1`, being optional if you want to see any error messages.

Comment: I tried same but not working. I saved above as .bat but after running the entries are still there
`For /F Delims^= %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKCR') Do %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "%G" /F 1>NUL 2>&1`

Comment: Good! What happens if you remove `2>&1`?

Comment: Nothing. Here is the screenshot 
https://ibb.co/8jrzQVf

Comment: That's a [[tag:batch-file]], your question and tags did not mention a batch-file, you used the [[tag:cmd]] tag, which is used for commands entered in Windows Command Prompt, i.e. cmd.exe. I have edited my answer to include the batch file version too, and edited your question to include the tag you should have used!

Comment: After running this, I cmd window pop up which is good but nothing has happened. Screenshot
https://ibb.co/mGKwC3F

Comment: Remove the `@echo off` line, if it was required I would have added it! I'll now ask that you run your batch file from a Command Prompt window, and once again remove `2>&1`. Then you should be able to see any error messages.

Comment: I launched CMD as administrator and removed `2>&1`. I am getting the below error
https://ibb.co/vLNrdnF

Comment: I just again run on a fresh machine and for some entry it is saying 
Error: Delete request is partially completed and for some 
Error: Access is denied

Comment: @Compo, while I agree that the OP can do anything with their own machine. I fear this will teach the OP how to do this to other machines. Surely there is some "learning" the OP could do without destroying a machine.

Comment: @SaPPi, that's exactly the behavior I'd expect if the batch file is run using a standard user account without the required access token. Why did you think that you could do this without taking steps to secure the appropriate permissions? How you run the script is not a programming issue, so I'll leave it to you to work out the next step.

Comment: @Compo I am using admin account of the machine not a standard account.

Comment: Using an admin account and running with the required access token is not the same thing @SaPPi, your comment therefore confirms nothing. Also, I expect that the 'Run as administrator' token may be insufficient to satisfy your requirements. Also, have you tried the method mentioned at the foot of my answer, via recent edit.

Comment: @SaPPi, does that mean that the method at the foot of my answer worked for you? If so, I can edit it so that just the solution exists. Additionally, in that case, could you please clean up your comments, so that future readers are not distracted by unnecessary bloat. Also, if it did work for you, it would be appreciated were you to mark it as accepted, so that it is considered as solved by the site.

Comment: Hello @Compo
I would say most of the part is working. I'm unable to use system. However, shutdown and restart are working but the system after last command is completely useless. This is the most reasonable solution so far to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are asking for with `reg delete` as you have shown it, as specifying `HKCR` by itself is illegal per the documentation when running `reg delete /?` on the command line:

```
REG DELETE KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve | /va] [/f]

  KeyName    [\\Machine\]FullKey
    Machine  Name of remote machine - omitting defaults to the current machine.
             Only HKLM and HKU are available on remote machines.
    FullKey  ROOTKEY\SubKey
    ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
    SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.

  ValueName  The value name, under the selected Key, to delete.
             When omitted, all subkeys and values under the Key are deleted.

  /ve        delete the value of empty value name (Default).

  /va        delete all values under this key.

  /f         Forces the deletion without prompt.

Examples:

  REG DELETE HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp\Timeout
    Deletes the registry key Timeout and its all subkeys and values

  REG DELETE \\ZODIAC\HKLM\Software\MyCo /v MTU
    Deletes the registry value MTU under MyCo on ZODIAC
```

Note how `KeyName` is defined as `[\\Machine\]FullKey` and `FullKey` is defined as `ROOTKEY\SubKey`, which mean you MUST specify a particular `SubKey` when specifying `HKCR` as the `ROOTKEY`. You can't omit the `SubKey`.

So, you will have to instead enumerate the subkeys under `HKCR` (such as with `reg query`), deleting each subkey one at a time.

Comment: Do you have exact command?

Comment: Hey, It is not about making my PC clear. I am learning on dummy machine.